How can i achive wood texture as show in reference image
i try using magic and noise texture and do some experiment but not getting desire result.
please check blender.file if you have any idea about this
enter image description here


enter image description here

blender file link : https://we.tl/t-KSayB0FyVI

A good, realistic wood texture is not easy to achieve procedurally, which is why many people often use image textures instead. And there is not one single perfect way, so this question is very likely to draw opinion-based result. There are many downloadable materials on the internet and many tutorials on Youtube on how to create wood materials, some even spreading over multiple videos...

Maybe,  mix 2 Noise Texture nodes that have a different Scale (in order to make big stains and small stains) and that are stretched on Y, through a Color > Mix Color, use the same mix to add a bit of Bump:

